# Import errors in Numba

Tags: python, vectorization, numba

The code :::: Does anyone can help me with this ?

```
from numba import vectorize

@vectorize(['int64(int64, int64)'], target='cuda')
def add_ufunc(x, y):
    return x + y


print('a+b:\n', add_ufunc(a, b))
print()
print('b_col + c:\n', add_ufunc(b_col, c))
```

The error ::::

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "array.py", line 1, in
>   
>       from numba import vectorize   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/**init**.py", line 11, in
>   
>       from . import config, errors, _runtests as runtests, types   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/config.py", line 9, in
>   
>       import multiprocessing   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/**init**.py", line 16, in 
>       from . import context   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/context.py", line 6, in 
>       from . import reduction   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 136, in
>   
>       import array   File "/home/felipe/cuda/array.py", line 1, in 
>       from numba import vectorize ImportError: cannot import name 'vectorize' from 'numba'
>   (/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/**init**.py)

Comment: You haven't defined `a`,`b`, etc. in the code you have shown.  Apart from that I don't have any trouble running the first few lines of the code you have shown here.  Maybe your numba is not installed correctly, i.e. a machine setup issue.  You appear to be using python3 here, maybe try it with python 2.

Comment: Trying with Python 3.6 would involve less drastic change to the code than trying with python 2.x.

Comment: Also, maybe check these wheels for installing numba with Python 3.7: https://github.com/numba/llvmlite/issues/376